# R ggplot2: maintain original colors and group level order when plotting subsets of data on different layers

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, layer, pch

I have a very simple (albeit large) data frame with 2 numeric columns and 1 character grouping column, containing several `NAs`.

I am going to use `iris` as an example. Below, I just introduce random `NAs` in the `Species` column I want to use for grouping and coloring.

What I do here is to remake the `Species` column as a factor with "NA" (character) at the end. I make a palette with `gray` at the end, that I want to correspond to "NA".

```
data("iris")
set.seed(123)
na_rows <- sample(nrow(iris), 100, replace = F)
iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)
iris$Species[na_rows] <- "NA"
mylevels <- iris$Species[which(iris$Species!="NA")]
mylevels <- c(gtools::mixedsort(unique(mylevels)), "NA")
iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species, levels=mylevels)
plot_palette <- c("red","blue","green")
plot_palette <- c(plot_palette[1:length(mylevels)-1], "gray")
```

All good till here. Now I make my scatter plot like this:

```
grDevices::pdf(file="test1.pdf", height=10, width=10)
P <- ggplot2::ggplot(data=iris, ggplot2::aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) +
     ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=plot_palette)
P1 <- P + ggplot2::geom_point(pch=16, size=10, alpha=0.75)
print(P1)
grDevices::dev.off()
```

This produces this plot:

[image: test1]

Still all good till here. This is very close to what I want, but my actual data frame is very large, and many `non-NA` points are hidden behind the `NA` ones.

To avoid this, I am trying to plot first the subset of `NA` data, and then on an upper layer the subset of `non-NA` data. I try the code below:

```
grDevices::pdf(file="test2.pdf", height=10, width=10)
P <- ggplot2::ggplot(data=iris, ggplot2::aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) +
     ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=plot_palette)
P1 <- P + ggplot2::geom_point(data=function(x){x[x$Species == "NA", ]}, pch=15, size=10, alpha=0.75) +
          ggplot2::geom_point(data=function(x){x[x$Species != "NA", ]}, pch=16, size=10, alpha=0.75)
print(P1)
grDevices::dev.off()
```

This produces this plot:

[image: test2]

The problem I have here is very obvious, but I have no clue how to solve it.

I just want this second plot to be exactly like the first one, except for the "layering" with `NA` points behind. I want to maintain the original order of the `Species` levels in the legend, with `NA` at the end, and the same color correspondence, with `NA` associated to `gray`.

Notice I also changed the `pch` for `NA` points. A bonus would be to have the legend with just square for `NA` (at the bottoms), and just circles for the other samples.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for multiple layers. You could simply reorder your dataset so that the `NA`s get plotted first and for the shapes you could map `Species` on the `shape` aes and set the desired shape via `scale_shape_manual`:

```r
iris1 <- dplyr::arrange(iris, desc(Species))

P <- ggplot2::ggplot(data=iris1, ggplot2::aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species, shape = Species)) +
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=plot_palette)
P + ggplot2::geom_point(size=10, alpha=0.75) + ggplot2::scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 16, 16, 15))
```

[image]